# > Спроси(,/:) товар привезли?

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания (двоеточие или запятая) должен быть поставлен вместо **?** в данном предложении:

> Спроси**?** товар привезли?

Comment: Не совсем ясен вопрос.

Comment: Например: Один человек даёт указание второму, чтобы тот спросил у третьего. Как-то так )))

Comment: Здесь сложное предложение. Поэтому нужна запятая.

Answer (score 2):

Нужна запятая, здесь нет пояснительного значения.

Answer (score 1):

Может, лучше написать так: «Узнай, привезли ли товар»? :)

Comment: Можно и так, но интересен первый вариант.)

Answer (score 1):

1) **БСП с прямым вопросом** (изъяснительное значение): Спроси: товар привезли?

Ну ты спроси, спроси конкретно: деньги-то у неё есть?

2) **СПП с придаточным изъяснительным**: Спроси, привезли ли товар.

Спроси, что она делала все эти сорок дней.

Спроси, скоро ли появится. Спроси, не надо ли чем помочь.

3) **Упрощенный вариант в разговорной речи (вводное предложение**):

Спроси, товар привезли?

В том случае структура БСП (с двоеточием), но интонация вводных конструкций.